How do I trigger Case assignment rules on case edit operation?
I know basically case assignment rules trigger on insertion of case. but i have expectation of want to trigger the case assignment rules for the edit operation. can you please help me ?
I have created the assignment rules and inserted the case record. I see that assignment rules are triggering but it is not for edit operation.

Depends on your entry point. If you're editing in standard UI - examine your page layout's hidden checkboxes

If you have custom edit form and the update goes via Apex: there's optional method you can call, search for dmloptions examples: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Database_AssignmentRuleHeader.htm
REST API has special http header, SOAP API has special node in the header's XML
Also read up on https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000395506&type=1
